# Unix read command with option -d and IFS variable combination

Tags: shell, unix

Looking forward to understand the behavior of ***read -d*** when it comes along with ***IFS*** variable

```
$ cat f1
a:b:c
d:e:f

$ while IFS= read -d: ; do echo $REPLY; done < f1
a
b
c d
e

$ while IFS=: read; do echo $REPLY; done < f1
a:b:c
d:e:f
```

Answer (score 7):

`IFS` is used when you're reading several variables with `read`:

```
$ echo foo:bar:baz | (IFS=: read FOO BAR BAZ; echo $FOO; echo $BAR; echo $BAZ)
foo
bar
baz
```

Whereas, the `-d` option specifies what your line separator for `read` is; `read` won't read beyond a single line:

```
$ echo foo:bar:baz%baz:qux:quux% | while IFS=: read -d% FOO BAR BAZ; do echo ---; echo $FOO; echo $BAR; echo $BAZ; done
---
foo
bar
baz
---
baz
qux
quux
```

Comment: Thank you [Chris Jester-Young](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young) for your explanation, but why the output for my code `$ while IFS= read -d: ; do echo $REPLY; done < f1` is giving as `
a
b
c d
e`  and not `a
b
c d
e
f $`. Why the char '**f**' and the newline got eliminated where as it is present in the case of '**c d**'

Comment: In Unix, many utilities assume that text files end with a newline. If the last line doesn't end with one, it's considered an incomplete line. In your case, since you're using a colon as your line separator, your input needs to end with a colon.

Answer (score 1):

IFS is inter field separator.
You say to shell which symbols is used to split fields.
It is used in two directions, not only when reading.

One special case that you use here is `IFS=`. You use `IFS=` here to correctly handle input starting with spaces.

You can compare:

```
echo "  a" | IFS= read a
echo "  a" | read a
```

That is important when you handle files and they can contain leading spaces in their names.

Please compare:

```
$ echo "  a" | ( IFS= read a; echo .$a. )
. a.
$ echo "  a" | ( read a; echo .$a. )
.a.
```

**UPDATE.** As you probably already noted,
this construction

```
$ echo a | read a
```

doesn't work. Because shell creates a subshell for the '''read''', and you can see the value of `$a` only inside it.

You can also use `while`, what is more often:

```
$ echo a | while read a; do echo $a; done
```

Comment: `echo "  a" | read IFS= a` throws error and when I changed it to `echo "  a" | IFS= read a; echo $a` then I see an empty line or blank line as output. The same goes with the second line of your code. So I do not see any difference in their outputs.

Comment: Please see my update. The problem with `read a` that you can access `$a` only in the subshell

Comment: So **IFS** variable is used to include space character while **read** reading the input line?

Comment: IFS is set separator to null; that is why the leading spaces are not striped. Read read the text in the variable