# unzip: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, unzip

everyone.
I have CSV file with ~1.5mil strings with column "ArchiveName", and i'm trying to unzip every archive with script:

```
#!/bin/bash
csvPath=/any/folder/ArchiveName.csv
archiveFolderPath=/any/archives
cd $archiveFolderPath
while IFS=";" read -r ArchiveName
do 
    unzipPath=/any/unzip
    sudo unzip "${ArchiveName}" -d "${unzipPath}"
done < <(tail -n +1 $csvPath)
```

When i'm start script - get error "Argument list too long"

i'm tried to cut csv file to 5k string, but it still doesn't work..
How i can change script or csv to make it alive?

Comment: Means what it says: argv uses the same pool of space as environment variables; the more you `export`, the shorter your maximum command-line length. Mind, it's only the _name_ of the archive, not the _contents_ of the archive, that count against that limit.

Comment: `set -x` or `bash -x yourscript` is your friend, if you don't think there should be any long command lines.

Comment: Also, btw, it's `< <(tail ...)` not `< < (tail ...)`; `<(` is a single token to the parser and doesn't work if there's an extra space added.

Comment: In terms of how you could get a much longer value than you expect in `ArchiveName` -- `IFS=';'` doesn't _do_ anything when you only provide one destination variable and aren't using `read` in array mode, so your entire first line is ending up in one variable, not being split by semicolons. Maybe you want `while read -r -d ';' ArchiveName || [[ $ArchiveName ]]; do`; `-d` sets the _record_ delimiter, as opposed to IFS setting _field_ delimiters.

Comment: ...indeed, if that's the whole of the misunderstanding (and I suspect it is), then this question is duplicative of [unix read command with option `-d` and IFS variable combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679141/unix-read-command-with-option-d-and-ifs-variable-combination)

Comment: (each call  to `read` reads one _record_, terminated by either a newline or an alternate character provided with `-d`, and then splits that record into _fields_ using IFS; but when you only provide one destination variable and don't use array mode, there's only one field needed so the split operation doesn't happen)

Comment: Anyhow -- if I'm misunderstanding the above, maybe [edit] the question to add a sample of the CSV file content? If you want to read only the first column and ignore future ones, f/e, then IFS and the default `-d` is correct but you need to add an additional variable name to act as a destination for extra content past that first column; so something like `while IFS=';' read -r ArchiveName _`, so everything _past_ the first `;` goes into a dummy variable named `_` instead of being appended to ArchiveName as it is by default.

Comment: In general, `read` is insufficient for parsing CSV.  It can be made to do the job for some restricted dialects of CSV and for some specific documents, but you would probably be better off using a for-purpose CSV reader.

Comment: Note also that if you mean `;` to be taken as a *record* specifier, as @CharlesDuffy suspects, then the `tail -n +1` command you're using to (I assume) skip a header record would need somehow to accommodate that too.  Furthermore, it looks like you are assuming [GNU `tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), for which `tail -n +1 foo` is equivalent to `cat foo`.  That is, you're not, in fact, skipping any records after all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `< < (tail ...)` must be a copying error, because it would cause a syntax error as written.

Comment: Please do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs and "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". If you still have a problem after fixing the issues that shellcheck will tell you about then post a question with your shellcheck-fixed code.

Comment: I think not related to your problem: `archiveFolderPath=/any/arhives` is missing a `c` in `arhives`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Argument list is too long" means: one of the strings you pass to `sudo unzip "${ArchiveName}" -d "${unzipPath}"` is too long (not: there are too many lines in your csv).

One way to debug that issue is to check what values are passed to your command:

```
echo "unzipping ${ArchiveName} ..."
sudo unzip "${ArchiveName}" -d "${unzipPath}"
```

---

If you have long csv lines where ArchiveName is the first field: you got tricked by the behavior of `read`.

`read` will place all the remaining fields in the last variable you specify. Here is an example:

```
$ IFS=";" read one <<<"foo;bar;baz"
$ echo $one
foo;bar;baz
$ IFS=";" read one two <<<"foo;bar;baz"
$ echo $one
foo
$ echo $two
bar;baz
```

In your code: `ArchiveName` contains the complete csv line (not: just the first field)

Just add a second variable to your call to `read` :

```
while IFS=";" read -r ArchiveName _discard
do ...
```

Comment: Thanks, echo "unzipping ${ArchiveName} ..."  was helpfull, found few errors in my script
1) Wrong delimiter, my bad :/
2) "_discard" helps to "read" string